# MSVC vs GCC: variable declaration in function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-studio-2010

As everybody knows, C standard require to declare variables at the top of function body.

C++ allows to declare it anywhere, just before it will be used.

MSVC follow standard when work with .c and .cpp source files.

GCC allows to declare variables anywhere in function body even if source file is .c

I have a huge number .c files compiling well in GCC and not in MSVC due to this. I can't rename all them to .cpp.

Is there any simple way to tell MSVC compiler to treat .c file as C++ ones?

Comment: Beware that C (especially C99) is not a subset of C++, so this might not work.

Comment: It's not at the top of the function body: it's at the top of the block (inside the block). The following snippet is valid C: `int main(void) {int a; {int top_of_block; top_of_block = 42; } a = 42; return 0;}`

Comment: I don't want to discourage honest questions, but you seem very unfamiliar with the C standards (specifically C89 and C99) to start your question with "As everybody knows …"

Comment: Oh yes, so GCC just treat .c as C99, that's right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C89 standard required that. Current C99 one doesn't. Anyway, the switch is `/TP` to treat all the input files as C++ and `/Tp<file>` to treat a select one — keep in mind that this might not fix anything, but also introduce new errors *and* it will mangle the names, so interop might be hurt.

The best solution would be to simply compile the C part with GCC.

Comment: It's reasonably shocking that VC **2010** still does not implement C99. What's the rationale for that?

Comment: @Kerrek MSVC is a C++ compiler with selected C features. They had a "bug" report or feature request for C99 full compatibility but they dismissed it with the rationale i said in the first sentence.

Comment: @RedX: Interesting. Is there no dedicated C compiler made by Microsoft, then?

Comment: @Kerrek: Nope.  The demand just isn't there, from their perspective.

Comment: @Kerrek: The GNU compiler collection still doesn't fully implement C99, either.

Comment: @David: Yes, that's actually also fairly shocking.

Answer (score 3):

In VisualStudio 2010, go to the properties for your project.  Go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced

For "Compile As" select "Compile as C++ Code (/TP).

This appears to apply to all .c and .cpp files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

The setting /TP allows to compile any file as C++ File and /TC as C-File.
But unfortunately, this is a per-file-setting. So you would have to set this for every file. 
Maybe you can do that with a small script and parse the .vcproj file and replace /TC with /TP.

Comment: Thanks, that is better than nothing!

Answer (score 1):

`/Tp`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55(v=vs.80).aspx

MSVC only supports C89.